# create template with regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to create a template on openvswitch.log with regular expression. I have openvswitch.log like follow text ;

```
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00010|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports recirculation
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00011|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: MPLS label stack length probed as 1
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00012|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports truncate action
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00013|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports unique flow ids
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00014|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports ct_state
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00015|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports ct_zone
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00016|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports ct_mark
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00017|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports ct_label
2017-05-18T06:40:02.850Z|00018|ofproto_dpif|INFO|system@ovs-system: Datapath supports ct_state_nat
2017-05-18T06:40:02.861Z|00001|ofproto_dpif_upcall(handler1)|INFO|received packet on unassociated datapath port 0
2017-05-18T06:40:02.861Z|00019|bridge|INFO|bridge s1: added interface s1-eth2 on port 2
2017-05-18T06:40:02.862Z|00020|bridge|INFO|bridge s1: added interface s1-eth1 on port 1
2017-05-18T06:40:02.862Z|00021|bridge|INFO|bridge s1: added interface s1-eth3 on port 3
2017-05-18T06:40:02.865Z|00022|bridge|INFO|bridge s1: added interface s1 on port 65534
2017-05-18T06:40:02.865Z|00023|bridge|INFO|bridge s2: added interface s2-eth3 on port 3
2017-05-18T06:40:02.869Z|00024|bridge|INFO|bridge s2: added interface s2-eth2 on port 2
2017-05-18T06:40:02.869Z|00025|bridge|INFO|bridge s2: added interface s2-eth1 on port 1
2017-05-18T06:40:02.873Z|00026|bridge|INFO|bridge s2: added interface s2 on port 65534
2017-05-18T06:40:02.873Z|00027|bridge|INFO|bridge s1: using datapath ID 0000000000000001
2017-05-18T06:40:02.873Z|00028|connmgr|INFO|s1: added service controller "punix:/var/run/openvswitch/s1.mgmt"
2017-05-18T06:40:02.873Z|00029|connmgr|INFO|s1: added service controller "ptcp:6654"
2017-05-18T06:40:02.873Z|00030|connmgr|INFO|s1: added primary controller "tcp:192.168.29.87:6633"
2017-05-18T06:40:02.873Z|00031|rconn|INFO|s1<->tcp:192.168.29.87:6633: connecting...
2017-05-18T06:40:02.877Z|00032|bridge|INFO|bridge s2: using datapath ID 0000000000000002
```

For instance ;

bridge ***s1:*** added interface ***s1-eth2*** on port ***0***

I want to search "bridge ... added interface ... on port ..." 
How can I found  this template  with  regular expression? I'll use java language

I wrote a java code but  it didn't find a result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("bridge (s.*?): added interface (s.*?) on port (\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p1.matcher("bridge s1: added interface s1-eth2 on port 0");
        String log_output = "";

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, " ");
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }
```

Have a nice  day  everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you need to use that regex? You can detect your lines (and group the individual s1/s1-eth2/0 results) with:

```
bridge (.*?): added interface (.*?) on port (\d+)
```

Replace spaces with `\s` or `\s+` if you expect the separators to be different (tabs for example) or have more than one whitespace character.

Edit: You didn't specify what language you use and how do you want to use the regex. Here's how to get to the groups in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("bridge (s.*?): added interface (s.*?) on port (\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p1.matcher("bridge s1: added interface s1-eth2 on port 0");
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Matched: " + m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ", " + m.group(3));
        // outputs: Matched: s1, s1-eth2, 0
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't find a result :(

Comment: You didn't specify what do you want to do with the regex, nor what language you use. Check the updated answer.

Comment: my fault I'm replace " " so that  it don't show me a result. Thank you very much again